# How to calculate width by MigLayout manually

Tags: android, miglayout

I'm using [MigLayout 4 Android](https://github.com/saynomoo/mig4android) in my android project. There is a bug in that code: if a child layout nested in a parent layout, the constraints like `fill, grow` will be ignored, because mig4android simply ignored them.

I'm trying to fix it, but I don't know how to do it.

For now, I can get the parent width, and the child's component constraints (may or may not have `grow`, `fill`, or else), how to calculate the child's width? Is there any methods provided by miglayout to do this?

Comment: I tried using example from git to see if I could help but couldn't get example to run

Answer (score 0):

please try this code
int Width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();